# How do I check if the values I am getting are increasing/decreasing?

Tags: python

First, let me specify a few things:

```
cleaned_example = [['I', 'horrible', 'physics', 'pretty', 'good', 'chemistry', 'excellent', 'math'], ['First', 'concerned', 'worried', 'scared'], ['What', 'started', 'bar', 'fight', 'turned', 'confrontation', 'finally', 'gang', 'war'], ['Every', 'hill', 'mountain', 'shall', 'made', 'low', 'rough', 'places', 'made', 'plain,', 'crooked', 'places', 'made', 'straight'], ['This', 'blessed', 'plot', 'earth', 'realm', 'England']]
```

but in reality is composed of 20 groups of words.

I am using the sentiment function which is part of pattern.en and I want to see if the sentiment values of the words in cleaned_example[0], cleaned_example[1].... are increasing or decreasing. The sentiment function outputs two values of the form (a,b) but I am only interested in the first of these values.

Here is what I have done so far. I am encountering two problems. First, I am getting 40 outputs when I should only be getting 20. Second, all of these outputs are 'no' so it is pretty useless.

```
for index in range(len(cleaned_example)):
for position in range(len(cleaned_example[index])-1):
    if sentiment(cleaned_example[index][position][0]) < sentiment(cleaned_example[index][position+1][1]):
        print('yes')
    else: 
        print('no')
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are expecting to get only 20 outputs, is it correct to assume you only want either a "yes" or a "no" for each group of words? I am not certain how exactly you want to measure that because you can just compare the sentiment of the first word and the last word in a list of words for each set in `cleaned_example`.

```
for words in cleaned_example:
    if sentiment(words[0])[0] < sentiment(words[-1])[0]:
        print "Increasing"
    else:
        print "Decreasing"
```

Another approach is to count the number of yes's and no's for each set of words.

```
for words in cleaned_example:
    yes = 0
    no = 0
    for word1, word2 in zip(words, words[1:]):
        if sentiment(word1)[0] < sentiment(word2)[0]:
            yes = yes + 1
        else: 
            no = no + 1
    if yes > no:
        print "yes"
    elif yes < no:
        print "no"
    else:
        print "`yes` = `no`"
```

Another approach is to obtain the average sentiment of a set and compare it with the sentiment of the first word.

```
import numpy as np

for words in cleaned_example:
    a_values = []
    for word in words:
        a_values.append(sentiment(word)[0])
    if sentiment(words[0])[0] < np.mean(a_values):
        print "Increasing"
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I hadn't thought of using the average like this.

Answer (score 3):

Going a step further than tom in avoiding indexing and using even more meaningful variable names (I googled that sentiment thing):

```
for sentence in cleaned_example:
    for word, next_word in zip(sentence, sentence[1:]):
        if sentiment(word)[0] < sentiment(next_word)[0]:
            print('yes')
        else: 
            print('no')
```

If for example `sentence` is `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`, then `sentence[1:]` is `['b', 'c', 'd']` and zipping them gives you word pairs `('a', 'b')`, `('b', 'c')` and `('c', 'd')`.

I don't know why you think you should get only 20 outputs (I get 36, btw, not 40). I suspect you are working at the wrong level and should use `sentiment` on *sentences*, not words? Note how I named my variable names, good names can really help you understand your code. Triple indexes not so much.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have parameters `(a,b)` and you only care about `a`, then you always want `[0]` when choosing between these; and I suspect that you have your parentheses in the wrong place as well.  That is, your difference line should read:

```
if sentiment(cleaned_example[index][position])[0] < sentiment(cleaned_example[index][position+1])[0]:
```

so the final index listed is `0` and not `1`, and you use `[0]` on the *value returned* from sentiment (ie, the `[0]` is to the right of the function call).

---

A few side notes:

This would read more easily if you didn't index `cleaned_example` every time:

```
for word_list in cleaned_example:
    for position in range(len(word_list)-1):
        if sentiment(word_list[position])[0] < sentiment(word_list[position+1])[0]:
            print('yes')
        else: 
            print('no')
```

Finally, here you're calling `sentiment` twice for almost every word.  If that's a problem then you should restructure your code a bit.  With this in mind, it would probably be better to start with something like:

```
for word_list in cleaned_example:
    sentiments = [sentiment(word)[0] for word in word_list]
    for i in range(len(sentiments)):
        if sentiments[i] < sentiments[i+1]:
            print('yes')
        else: 
            print('no')
```